# Files are being uploaded on all browsers and iPhone except for the iPad

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ipad, ios8

I have a web form that allows me to complete some text inputs and upload files. It works perfect on all browsers and iPhone ( with iOS 8 installed). When i am trying to upload files on iPad (iOS8 installed , tested on iPad air and iPad 3), i select the images and then when submitting the form, it loads for a long time and then drop the connection. I am using Safari on all iOS devices.

I am using the standard input file for upload.

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="upload" />
```

What should be the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 8 suffers from a bug in Safari where uploads do not go through (see: http://blog.uploadcare.com/post/97884147203/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari).  The 8.0.2 update fixes this.  It could be that your iPad is on 8.0 default and your iPhone is on 8.0.2.

Comment: Indeed, my iPad is 8.0, my iPhone is 8.0.2, i am updating the software right now and i will tell you if this was fixed.